# Dual Boot Windows & Ubuntu with Windows Boot Loader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, bootloader

I’m am wondering if I can dual boot Windows 10 Home (My current OS) with Ubuntu, but using the Windows boot loader. Is there any way I can do that? And can you list any problems that would happen if I do that? That would be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: If Windows 10 is pre-instlled then it is UEFI. And with UEFI you can boot all installed systems from UEFI boot menu, often f10 or f12, check your manual. Windows is not designed to boot other systems than Windows. You can add a BCD entry to reboot system into Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I would have to use the Grub boot loader. I have a HP Pavilion HPE h8-1214. The PC was made before HP started using UEFI or Windows 8. Thank you for answering!

Comment: Just make sure to also have a Windows repair/recovery flash drive. Windows 10 will turn on fast start up and then grub will not boot it. And it may turn that on with updates in the back ground. And if Windows gets corrupted and needs chkdsk, grub will not boot it. So have Windows repair tools as well   as Ubuntu live installer as repair tool.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I have done some research and decided to have Ubuntu as my main OS. I seems that it safer, easier to use, there is lots of great software for it, and it’s very secure.